# Monitoring resource usage of an Ajax web page automatically (prefereably in CI)

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, cpu-usage, performance-testing

I have a suite of selenium tests that I have just inherited that test the application repeatedly in order to monitor resource usage (memory is the primary concern). This is focused on the client side resource usage and not the server so the answer on how to monitor this is seemingly more obscure (if i was testing the server I would have a few ideas)

What they currently do is run a test X times (x is in the region of 100) while in another thread checking  the memory usage in total of IE and logging this. This seems far from an ideal in many ways what we really need is a profiler solution or something but I am unsure of any programmatic API i can call to use such a thing as part of the automated tests. I have been unable to find anything to meet what i thought would be better or even a completely different solution to get the data they require. Has anyone else tried anything like this?

I am happy to hear about completely different solutions to monitoring resource usage within a browser in an automated fashion.